# Declare global CheckBox variable in Word VBA

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, global-variables

My word-document has at minimum 2 `CheckBoxes`. I want to declare them as a global variable to use them often. For some reason I am unable to declare them as variables, which is bad.

```
Dim cb1 As CheckBox
Dim cb2 As CheckBox
'here are n CheckBoxes possible

cb1 = ActiveDocument.FormFields(1).CheckBox 'here I got a error
'same code for the n CheckBoxes
```

After I declared them as a global variable I want to set the value of cb2 to `False` if `cb1.Value = True`. With this:

```
If cb1.Value = True Then
    cb2.Value = False
End If
```

Hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to be able to work with the cb1, cb2 etc. variables in *one* VBA Module, then what you already have is nearly correct, assuming that

- your Dim Statements are at the top of a Module
- your other statements are actually inside Sub() or Function() definitions *and*
- there is a legacy checkbox formfield in the ActiveDocument (which is not necessarily the same document as the document/template that contains the code).

But cb1 is an object type, and in VBA that means that you have to use the Set statement to assign a *reference to an object* to cb1, i.e. you need

```
Set cb1 = ActiveDocument.FormFields(1).CheckBox
```

But you don't need the "Set" to assign values to non-object members, so your code to modify cb1.Value is OK.

If you really want to be able to use the cb1, cb2 variables in more than one Module, you can, but I would recommend that you avoid that if possible.

One way to do it is to modify your Dim Statements to be Public statements:

```
Public cb1 As CheckBox
Public cb2 As CheckBox
```

but outside the module containing those statements, you have to qualify the variable name using the name of the module that contains the "Public" statements. So if the "Public" statements are in a module called Module1, outside that module, you have to use

```
Set Module1.cb1 = ActiveDocument.FormFields(1).CheckBox
```

### Notes:

Although

```
Dim cb1 As CheckBox
```

is fine, it's a good practice to qualify the type as fully as you can, e.g.

```
Dim cb1 As Word.CheckBox
```

The reason for this practice is more obvious when you start working with more than one type of object in your code. For example, both Word and Excel have objects of type Range, but they are completely different types.

---

In VBA, it is always good practice to release object reference when you have finished using them. Unlike some environments that will do the "garbage collection" for you - eventually - VBA won't do that automatically. So somewhere your code should execute a line like this:

```
Set cb1 = Nothing
```

---

In VBA, if you omit the "Set", VBA thinks you are trying to assign the value of the *default member* of the Checkbox. You can find out what the default member is by searching for Word's Checkbox Class in View->Object Browser in the VB Editor. Select it, and you will see that one of its members is specially marked - in this case, it's "Valid".

So without the Set,

```
cb1 = ActiveDocument.FormFields(1).CheckBox
```

would mean "assign the value of `ActiveDocument.FormFields(1).CheckBox.Valid` to the cb1 variable". Since .Valid is a Boolean and cb1 is a CheckBox, that will cause an error.

---

There are several types of Checkbox in Word, and you can put at least three of them (legacy FormField checkbox, Content Control checkbox, and legacy ActiveX checkbox) in a document. But they all have different types, so if you are actually using a content control, none of the above will work!

Answer (score 1):

Try `Public cb1 As CheckBox, cb2 As CheckBox`. But make the declaration on top of the module. In the declarations area. **Not try it in a Sub**... You will receive another error.

And define it as following:

```
Set cb1 = ActiveDocument.FormFields(1)
```

Supposing that first `FormField` object is your check box. Otherwise, use:

```
Set cb1 = ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextBoxName") 'using its name...
```

Comment: You cannot declare a public variable in a Sub even if you wanted to. :)

Comment: @Kostas K.: Of course! I only wanted to prevent him trying this.  I had in mind what you say when writing and I asked myself if it is good to say it. But I tried to avoid another question about a new error... :)

Comment: @Kostas K.:  Good point yours, too. I modified the message to be more elocvent... :)